# "Package python is not installed.", even though it is installed?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, python

I'm following these instructions to install OS Spoofer on an Ubuntu virtual machine. Ubuntu is freshly installed, and I have not changed the "/etc/apt/sources.list" file

https://github.com/segofensiva/OSfooler-ng?tab=readme-ov-file

Here are the commands I've tried so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/segofensiva/OSfooler-ng.git

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nfqueue-bindings/python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
```

> Reading database ... 200577 files and directories currently
> installed.) Preparing to unpack python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
> ... Unpacking python-nfqueue (0.5-1build2) ... dpkg: dependency
> problems prevent configuration of python-nfqueue:  python-nfqueue
> depends on python (>= 2.7); however:   Package python is not
> installed.  python-nfqueue depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
> Package python is not installed.  python-nfqueue depends on
> libnetfilter-queue1; however:   Package libnetfilter-queue1 is not
> installed.  python-nfqueue depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7); however:
> Package libpython2.7 is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package python-nfqueue (--install):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
> processing:  python-nfqueue

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt-get install libpython2.7 libnetfilter-queue1

sudo dpkg -i python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
```

> Selecting previously unselected package python-nfqueue. (Reading
> database ... 201278 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> python-nfqueue (0.5-1build2) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of python-nfqueue:
> python-nfqueue depends on python (>=2.7); however:
> Package python is not installed.
> python-nfqueue depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
> Package python is not installed.
> dpkg: error processing package python-nfqueue (--install):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
> processing:  python-nfqueue

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

python2 --version
```

> Command 'python2' not found, but can be installed with:
> sudo apt install python2

```
sudo apt install python2

sudo dpkg -i python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
```

This simply results in the same error message as above.

I currently have installed:

Python 2.7.18

Python 3.10.12.

Please help me figure out how to fix this dependency.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried the following command, it gives me a new error message. I reverted my VM to a fresh install snapshot, and tried again, but same result:

```
sudo apt install ./python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Note, selecting 'python-nfqueue' instead of
> './python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb' Some packages could not be
> installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
> situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
> required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
> Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python-nfqueue :
> Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
> Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a message that says that `python (>= 2.7) is not installable`,  however python2.7 is in the default Ubuntu 22.04 repositories, so you need to restore the default repositories. You can recreate a standard sources.list in Ubuntu 22.04 and later by running the following commands.

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/backup.txt # back up existing sources.list file
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-backports main universe restricted multiverse
EOF
```

The python2.7 package is a dependency of python-nfqueue. Change directories with `cd` to the directory which contains python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb and install it together with its dependencies by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb
```

This command is similar to `sudo dpkg -i python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb` except that it installs the dependencies of python-nfqueue_0.5-1build2_amd64.deb too.

Comment: I tried using that command, but no luck. 

I've edited my original post above with the results of what happened when I tried that commmand. It results in a similar error message.

Comment: This is all happening on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, so I'm still using the default repositories. Regardless, I used these commands and I still got the "held broken package" error message.

Comment: Here is a link to a top upvoted question on solving the "held broken packages" error: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)

Comment: You might need to disable or remove your PPAs and other non-default software sources in `/etc/apt/` directory and subdirectories of `/etc/apt/` too.